# What is the orca package and can it be removed?

Tags: package-management, 18.04

The `orca` process seems to be the cause of [Bug #1788364](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1788364), that leaves the terminal and few other programmes unresponsive. I have to forcefully kill this process on every Ubuntu 18.04 session.

The purpose of this package is somewhat mysterious. This is the description provided by `apt`:

```
$ apt show orca
[...]
Description: Scriptable screen reader
 A flexible, extensible, and powerful assistive technology that
 provides end-user access to applications and toolkits that support the
 AT-SPI (e.g., the GNOME desktop).
 .
 Orca defines a set of default behaviors (reactions to application events) and
 key bindings (reaction to user key presses). These default behaviors and key
 bindings can be overwritten on a per-application basis. Orca creates a script
 object for each running application, which merges both the default behaviors
 and key bindings, and the application specific ones. Orca provides the
 infrastructure to activate and deactivate scripts, as well as a host of
 services accessible from within the scripts.
```

[Packages.ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/orca) does not add to this.

I have no idea which "default behaviours" are those, the DE and the system work exactly as expected after the `orca` process is killed. So, can it be simply removed? Or will it break something?

Comment: Looking at the output of a simulated purge might help: `apt purge -s orca`

Comment: What's mysterious in "Scriptable screen reader"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the output of `apt purge -s orca`

```
dkb@dkb:~$ apt purge -s orca
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  orca*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Purg orca [3.28.0-3ubuntu1]
dkb@dkb:~$
```

So it doesn't look like purging it will be a problem.

In addition, `orca` doesn't seem to be running on my system:

```
dkb@dkb:~$ ps -aux | grep orca
dkb       1999  0.0  0.0  21536  1044 pts/0    S+   16:09   0:00 grep --color=auto orca
dkb@dkb:~$
```

I don't know why you're having it running and so have a need to kill it.

Comment: So, I purged `orca`, this reslted in a number of exceptions from `docker.io` and `dpkg` exited with code 1. Let's see where this will all end.

Comment: Two notes: 1) `orca` is being installed during the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, verified this in other systems; 2) removing it is indeed harmless, whatever goes wrong with `dpkg` is eventually recovered automatically by the system.